# Not sure if service onDestroy is called from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-notifications

I have a service which I start using

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
```

When app is going into background, **not closed**, just not in foreground: i.e. press home button, I do:

```
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

To bring the service to the foreground and show ongoing notification.

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which is fired when the notification's **shut down** action is clicked (added action to notification).

The `BroadcastReceiver` stops the service:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    context.stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Now, there are two scenarios:

1. When app goes to background **but not closed!**, when pulling down the notification bar and clicking the **shut down** action -> the service's `onDestroy` is called just fine. I can see `Toast` and `Log` messages from `onDestroy`.
2. When app **is closed** (swiped away from apps list), meaning only service is running, when pulling down the notification bar and clicking the **shut down** action -> **it doesn't** look like the service's `onDestroy` is called! The code over there is not executed, and I **cant** see `Toast` and `Log` messages from `onDestroy`.

**However**, it seems that the service **does stop**, because I can see the app removed from **settings -> running apps** after clicking the **shut down**.

So, is the service getting destroyed? and if so, why isn't the code in `onDestroy` gets executed?

How can I make sure `onDestroy` is called?

Obviously it has something to do with the fact that in "good" scenario, the app is still in the background, and in the "bad" scenario, the app is closed.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to  CommonsWare's and John Leehey's comments, I understood that it could be that the "process is being terminated" and "there is no guarantee" that `onDestory()` will be called.

My `onDestory` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopLocationUpdates();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    Foreground.get(this).removeListener(this);
    // set default zoom
    sharedPrefrencesManager.putFloat(getString(R.string.zoom_last_location_key), 15);
    Log.i("test", "onDestroy");
}
```

Should I do the stuff like `stopLocationUpdates();` and `googleApiClient.disconnect();` in another place? since there is no guarantee of `onDestory` being called?

Comment: "So, is the service getting destroyed?" -- probably the process is being terminated. There is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called when this occurs. "How can I make sure onDestory is called?" -- in general, you don't. Both the user (e.g., Force Stop on your app in Settings) and the OS (e.g., urgent need for system RAM) can cause your process to be terminated without `onDestroy()` being called.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so to make sure I got it,  you say that the broadcastreceiver does execute the `context.stopService(serviceIntent)` and the service is destroyed, even though `onDestroy()` is not called?

Comment: It could be that your service detached from your logger before onDestroy() was called.  In your logcat, make sure you have "No Filters" set instead of "Show only selected application"

Comment: Ok. I am editing my question, will appreciate if you guys took a look

Comment: I am guessing that when the app is "closed" (swiped away from apps list), the `Service` is no longer running. Please check that.