# OnDestroy not being called for background Service in Android

Tags: android, service, background

I am facing similar problem as

[Not sure if service onDestroy is called from BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924379/not-sure-if-service-ondestroy-is-called-from-broadcastreceiver)

Since it has not been answered, I am creating new question. My Service code looks like below (full code not pasted):

```
public class GPSLogger extends Service implements LocationListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(GPSLogger.TAG, "StartAtBootService -- onStartCommand()");
        // lot of init code
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(freq);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(freq / 4);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Util.sendNotification("Service", "OnDestroy", this, 100);
        stopLocationUpdates();
        DBHelper.closeDb();
        Log.i(GPSLogger.TAG, "StartAtBootService Destroyed");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("cc.siara.gpslogger.RestartService");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

I can see from the ADB Log that the OS starts the service several times and calls onStartCommand.  But I can't find "StartAtBootService Destroyed" even once.

The device I am testing on is Samsung SM-J120G Android 5.1.1 API 22.

I know Android stops services once a while to release memory. But is there anyway I can run my cleanup code when Android does so?

Answer (score 1):

onDestroy will be called in the following scenarios -

1. When you stop self from the service.
2. When the os runs out of memory and decides to stop your app.
3. When you call stop service through an intent from activity or broadcast receiver.

Comment: Ok, I don't stop it myself or through intent. My scenario is No.2 that you have mentioned.. But still onDestroy does not seem to be called. Same problem is faced by other person I have linked in my question.

Comment: #2 is wrong, it wont run onDestroy for that, it will just kill the service/activity skipping the onDestroy.

Comment: If so, is there any other way I can clean up / close stuff in case of #2 ?